# Python Turtle - How do I stop the turtle at a specific distance or coordinate?

Tags: python, coordinates, distance, turtle-graphics

This is my attempt to make the turtle stop after traveling nearly 400 pixels.

```
def race():
    while True:
        alex.forward(r_alex)
        a = a + r_alex
        if a > 399.9:
            break
```

And this is what I got back

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `a = a + r_alex` uses `a` before you actually define `a`.

I'm guessing `a` is the turtle's displacement so perhaps you should try the following:

```
def race():
    a = 0
    while True:
        alex.forward(r_alex)
        a += r_alex
        if a > 399.9:
            break
```

Even better:

```
def race():
    a = 0
    while(a > 399.9):
        alex.forward(r_alex)
        a += r_alex
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand the problem now!